# How can I add a stylesheet dynamically with NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my nextJS application, I need to load a stylesheet dynamically based on the user preference received from the database.

So, in my page, I'm adding it in the Head (next/head), as follows:

```
<Head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href={`/fonts/${type}/stylesheet.css`}></link>
</Head>
```

However, this is giving me a warning in the console in development mode:

```
Do not add stylesheets using next/head (see <link rel="stylesheet"> tag with href="/fonts/cal/stylesheet.css"). Use Document instead. 
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-stylesheets-in-head-component
```

The stylesheet itself contains the font-face:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Cal Sans";
  src: url("CalSans-SemiBold.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("CalSans-SemiBold.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

Since the user's preference is stored in the database, and I receive this value via a query, I don't know how I can add it to the Document.js file.

I'll really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: The error literally gives you a link to an explanation. From there you can see a link to a tutorial on creating a Custom Document in which you can add stylesheet links. The tutorial explains how to use `getInitialProps` to load data you need.

Comment: @zoran404 I don't think that's right in Dec 2023 with the introduction of the app router and the docs update. I don't see a proper way to dynamically include stylesheets in the docs any more and `getInitialProps` isn't for app router either.

Comment: @FrankenCode His question is about the error that happens when using the pages folder and for his case the linked tutorial is still valid. With the app folder you instead add styles in the layout.tsx file.

Comment: Agreed that this is valid for pages router. I'm leaving the comment up in case someone is looking for a solution while using app router. With the app router, you cannot simply add a `<link rel='stylesheet' />` in your Layout.tsx file without the next compiler screaming at you. That's how I got to this question in the first place. :') Will go and ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This problem is resolved in the new Nextjs version where they provide support for Font Optimization, as documented here - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization

It also supports font self-hosting which was the key to my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

While it might be possible to dynamically import a CSS file in your main app component (and you can check out an example [in this guide](https://medium.com/swlh/dynamically-import-css-d8222423f109)), I would suggest a different solution.

Include all stylesheets in your application, but make its styles only apply when the `html` (or `body`) element has a certain class. Then all you need to do is modify that class based on user preference.

```
// styles.css
body.themeFoo #container {
  // some styles...
}
```

This is how many implementations of dark mode work, e.g. in tailwind CSS. I believe this is a better pattern to solve your problem.

Comment: This sounds interesting. However, if I include all stylesheets, will it not increase the page size?

Comment: yes, that could be a valid concern. depends on how many different stylesheets you have and how big they are. but you should probably measure the impact it has on performance, as it could be negligible.

Comment: I'm loading Google Fonts stylesheets on demand for a web app in which the user can select any font from Google Fonts. It's not feasible to load all of them upfront.

Answer (score -3):

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="..." />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is a very low effort answer. You just copied the example code from the link in the OP's question.